# Gettext extension on PHP 5.3.13 on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, php

I recently bought a new MacBook and I'm trying to configure it for PHP development.

The operating system is OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion, and I'm using the builtin Apache2 and PHP 5.3.13 stack.

I needed to install some extensions: mcrypt and intl. Both were re-compiled by me (from the source, either from PECL or from the tarball of PHP 5.3.13, using "phpize" then "./configure" and so on) and were installed and activated perfectly.

I'm having issues with the *gettext* extension. I'm trying to use the one included in PHP 5.3.13 tarball, and I can compile it and install it. The extension is loaded successfully by the interpreter but... It does not work!
In fact, when I call for example the *bindtextdomain* function, I get a PHP error saying it doesn't exist.

Additionally, "make test" return some errors.

The dependency (the gettext library) was installed using MacPorts (version: 0.18.1.1, Revision 2).

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd been stumbling on this for the last day too. Having installed gettext from MacPorts (`port install gettext`) and trying to configure php-gettext from the correct version php source, it would create the extension, but only the gettext() and bindtextdomain() functions were available in php.

A closer look at the output from configure shows lines such as `checking for ngettext in -lintl... no`

A colleague pointed out that Mac has it's own stripped down version of gettext, so figured that the configure was using that libintl for checking library over the MacPorts version.

Some info [posted on a forum](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=64#p1656) in answer to someone having a similar problem for different software on FreeBSD showed me some flags to force it to look in the MacPorts directories first. I used the configure line below, and now all the gettext functions are available in PHP:

```
./configure --with-gettext=/opt/local CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all, I edited it to add CFLAGS along with CPPFLAGS (because some files are C). This is not fully working, though: now it fails only 1 test (compared to many more it was failing before), but it's the "Gettext basic test" one. And it's still not working in the web server...

Comment: I think the problem is that it's still linking against ICU in /usr/local instead of /opt/local... This despite the various flags! (Had a similar issue in the past with other programs)

Comment: Here's the full output: http://pastie.org/4449887

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. 'otool' shows that the extension is correctly linked against libraries in /opt/local: http://pastie.org/4449898 ... So, why is it not working??

Comment: Bizarre, worked for me with just the flags that I entered. Did you `make clean` and `phpize --clean` before starting again? I forgot and so make and make install didn't update the extension, but it worked fine on two identical Macbook Pros with ML once we started clean.

Comment: I did make clean, and also manually removed the gettext.so file from the extension dir. I didn't do "phpize --clean", but I've just tried and it doesn't help.

Comment: My full process:
`sudo port install icu gettext
cd php-5.3.13/etc/itnl
phpize
./configure --enable-itnl
make
sudo make install

cd ../gettext
phpize
./configure --with-gettext=/opt/local CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib
make
sudo make install`

Added `extension=intl.so` and `extension=gettext.so` to my php.ini and restarted apache `sudo apachectl graceful`

Unfortunately I don't think there's anything else that I can add, as this seemed to sort it for me.

Comment: What happens when you run "make test"?

Comment: Oh, that formatting really messed up! What happened to all the line-breaks!?  You're right, I get that same failed test, but all my translations seem to be working OK so far. `FAIL Gettext basic test [tests/gettext_basic.phpt]`

Comment: I get: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function bindtextdomain() in [...]"

Answer (score 0):

[An alternative can be using Zend Server for Mac](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads?src=downloadb).

Comment: That means having more apps and more complications... I'd rather stick with the official Apache2: it's just a testing environment, eventually.